# Two tables below are each other

Tags: excel

In a sheet, I have two table bellow are each other and those tables are in records extending.
I what when above table create new record, not approaching to below table and their distance (count of lines (empty or not empty) are between them)  been constant.
How can it been possible?

I will try more explain my subject:
In a sheet, I have two Tables. Table1 range is: $A$1:$F$100 and Table2 range is: $A$110:$Z$300. One of this two Tables are below each other and has 10 lines distance between them. When above one inserts new row, distance of tables will decreased to 9 lines and upper one approaching below one. I want when pressing Tab in last cell of upper Table, when creates new record, that not penetrate the bottom table.

Comment: Sorry but no idea what you are talking about...please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Comment: In a sheet, I have two Tables. Table1 range is: $A$1:$F$100 and Table2 range is: $A$110:$Z$300. One of this two Tables are below each other and has 10 lines distance between them. When above one inserts new row, distance of tables will decreased to 9 lines and upper one approaching below one. I want when pressing Tab in last cell of upper Table, when creates new record, that not penetrate the bottom table.